# Ajax doesn't update on hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

I followed **[this guide](http://html5beta.com/jquery-2/a-little-guide-about-jqueryui-tooltip-ajax-callback/)** to make an Ajax example of jQueryUI tooltip **([Demo](http://painfulmouth.com/test/tooltip.html))**. I tweak it a bit to make it load different files by using data attributes. I can get the first content upon page load but when I hover on the second title, it doesn't retrieve the second content and still shows the first one. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

```
$(document).tooltip({
      items: "[data-info]",

      content: function () {
            return $(this).data('info');
      },
      show: null, 
      close: function (event, ui) {
            ui.tooltip.hover(

          function () {
                $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
          },

          function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("150", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
          });
        }
});

$('.loadtip').tooltip({
      my: "center",
      at: "right+200",
      track: false,

      content:function(callback) { //callback
       var loadfile = $('.loadtip').data("info");

        $.get(loadfile,{}, function(data) {
            callback(data);

        });

      },

});
```

HTML:

```
<h4 title="" class="loadtip" data-info="First.html">View Info</h3>

<h4 title="" class="loadtip" data-info="Second.html">View Detail</h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var loadfile = $(this).data("info");
```

instead of:

```
var loadfile = $('.loadtip').data("info");
```

inside your `content` function.